# Creating a Reusable Enum to Checkbox List using Razor Pages Partial, TagHelper or ViewComponent

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I am attempting to create a neat, reusable checkbox list for enums with the [flags] attribute in Razor Pages with .NET Core 7.

I do not know which worflow to use - Partial, TagHelpers, ViewComponent or any others (or a combination), neither how I might apply these tools (having no experience creating any of them) to create a clean, efficient and reusable tool/helper.

The code below works, but it is not particularly reusable - for example, if I wanted to change the html so the `label` element became a parent of the `checkbox input`, I will need to change this in every instance of the 'cut and pasted' cshtml code.

In addition, the call to the helper function `MyHtmlHelpers.EnumToCheckboxList<Urgency>(nameof(TransportReferral), nameof(TransportReferral.Urgency), TransportReferral?.Urgency)`  seems verbose and inefficient when compared to TagHelpers. Instead, it would be ideal to be able to access all these arguments with a single reference - in a similar way the TagHelpers do with the `asp-for` attribute, but I do not know how this might be achieved.

```
public static partial class MyHtmlHelpers
{
    public static IEnumerable<CheckboxListItem> EnumToCheckboxList<TEnum>(string? modelName, string propertyName, TEnum? enumValue) where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        string name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelName)
            ? propertyName
            : modelName + '.' + propertyName;
        string idPrefix = name.Replace('.', '_');
        return Enum.GetValues<TEnum>().Select(e =>
        {
            var eStr = e.ToString();
            var eInt = Convert.ToInt32(e).ToString();
            // ignoring DisplayAttribute.Name
            return new CheckboxListItem
            {
                Display = typeof(TEnum).GetMember(eStr)[0]
                    .GetCustomAttributes<DescriptionAttribute>(false)
                    .FirstOrDefault()?
                    .Description ?? SplitCamelCase(eStr),
                IsChecked = enumValue.HasValue && enumValue.Value.HasFlag(e),
                Value = eInt,
                Name = name,
                Id = idPrefix + '_' + eInt,

            };
        }).ToList();
    }
    public static string SplitCamelCase(string input)
    {
        return lowerUpper().Replace(input, "$1 $2");
    }

    [GeneratedRegex("([a-z])([A-Z])", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant)]
    private static partial Regex lowerUpper();

}
public class CheckboxListItem
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

consumed in a `cshtml` page like so:

```
@foreach (var e in MyHtmlHelpers.EnumToCheckboxList<Urgency>(nameof(TransportReferral), nameof(TransportReferral.Urgency), Model.TransportReferral?.Urgency))
{
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" 
            name="@e.Name"
            id="@e.Id"
            checked="@e.IsChecked"
            value="@e.Value">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="@e.Id">
            @e.Display
        </label>
    </div>
}
```

So in summary, is there a way to refactor the above code, taking advantage of Razor pages tools, to make the cshtml markup more reusable and *also* allow the full name `TransportReferral.Urgency` *and* its value to be passed cleanly to the tool with a single argument, similarly to (or in the same way) the `asp-for` attribute does for taghelpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you want to do is replicate the `SelectTagHelper` with `enum` support, except you want to render checkboxes instead of option elements. Given that, I would start with the source code for the `SelectTagHelper`
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/SelectTagHelper.cs
and the `GetEnumSelectList` helper https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/HtmlHelper.cs#L398